# Homebrew does not upgrade pyenv

Tags: homebrew, pyenv

I'm trying to upgrade `pyenv` with `homebrew` for getting [new Python releases](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/commit/835707da2237b8f69560b2de27ae8ddd3e6cb1a4).

Here is the problem:

```
$ brew upgrade pyenv
Error: pyenv 1.2.7 already installed
```

Is there a kind of update latency in homebrew package versioning? I am aware of the existence of other ways to install `pyenv`, but I'd like to use homebrew.

Comment: I'm seeing the same. 

```
> brew upgrade pyenv

Warning: pyenv 1.2.20 already installed
```

I'm not seeing newer versions of python that I know are available for install with `pyenv install --list`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pyenv 1.2.8 is not yet officially released.

On the master branch the last tag is 1.2.7.

The commit you mentioned in your question is in preparation for release 1.2.8.

Version 1.2.7 is here https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/tree/v1.2.7

Version 1.2.8 should be here https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/tree/v1.2.8 but nothing is there (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Verify `which pyenv` your system is using.

I thought I had this issue but then realized I had two different installs on my computer and my system was *not* actually using the brew installed `pyenv --version`.

Grepping my shell `history`, I saw that at some point I installed pyenv with curl using pyenv-installer for some reason. The command I found in my history was `curl https://pyenv.run | bash`. I followed the pyenv-installer directions to [uninstall](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer#uninstall). Make sure to restart your shell once you uninstall!

I then reinstalled pyenv with brew. `brew reinstall pyenv` though I'm not sure if that's necessary.

I now see the newer versions of python available for install with `pyenv install --list`